# How to tag an OS disk after VM deployment with Azure PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell

After VM deployment (with **ARM** or **Bicep**) I want to tag the OS disk, so that I can  relate the disk to the VM more easily - because it is not automatically tagged like the VM.

Answer (score 0):

After deployment which goes something like this

```
$parameters = @{ }
$parameters['virtualMachineName'] = $virtualMachineName
$parameters['adminUsername'] = $adminUsername
$parameters['adminPassword'] = $adminPassword
$parameters['location'] = $location
$parameters['virtualMachineSize'] = "Standard_D4s_v3"
$parameters['osDiskType'] = "Premium_LRS"
$parameters['publicIpAddressType'] = "Dynamic"
$parameters['publisher'] = $publisher
$parameters['offer'] = $offer
$parameters['sku'] = $sku
$parameters['version'] = $vmImage.Version

$deploymentName = $virtualMachineName
$templateName = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "main.bicep"

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name $deploymentName `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -TemplateFile $templateName `
    -TemplateParameterObject $parameters `
    -Verbose
```

I retrieve the said VM + OS disk and set the tag I want:

```
# tag disk
$diskName = (Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $virtualMachineName).StorageProfile.OsDisk
Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DiskName $diskName | % { New-AzTag -ResourceId $_.Id -Tag @{"vmName" = $virtualMachineName } }
```